# generating CSS triangles for a wordpress menu

Tags: css, wordpress

(Note: when I started this question I hadn't solved it, but now having solved it, I would like to understand why/how it works one way and not the other)

I wanted to add a CSS triangle pointing to the current menu item in the menu bar. I borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616418/adding-small-arrow-under-current-page-in-wordpress-with-css) and I got a working solution (on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madivad/z5ou6x7y/)).

But when I took the code for the bottom CSS

`li .selected::after`

and put it into my wordpress CSS, it didn't work.

Figuring I messed up the wordpress classes, I played with it for over an hour and couldn't determine why it wouldn't work. When I removed the `li` and put the `id` field in, it worked. I kept playing with it and finally got to a working solution by removing the space and making it:

`li.selected::after`.

The problem I had is that on jsfiddle it only works if there IS a space between the element and the class, but in wordpress, it only works if there is NO space between them.

I'm not great with CSS and it's syntax, but which is (more?) correct?

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="special-nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-item selected">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#000;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
}
.menu a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
li .selected::after {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    left: 50%;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}
```

edit: @rnevius hit it in one, here the HTML from wordpress for the same section (the class is a part of the `li` and not a child of it. Thanks very much.

```
<li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-94"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax works like this...

A space between `li` and a class selector means:

*I'm targeting a DIFFERENT (child) element, within a `li`, with a class of `.selected`.*

Without a space, you're saying:

*I'm targeting a `li` element that has a `class="selected"`.*

Quite simply, **a space means you're no longer referring to the same element.** The only reason things would be different between the fiddle and WordPress is if there's an actual difference between the way the HTML elements (and classes) are generated on the WordPress page.

See [parsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#parser-entry-points) in the spec, for more technical info.

Comment: Thanks, that's crystal clear and to demonstrate that, I've included the wordpress html which verifies what you're saying. The class is a part of the list item, whereas in my jsfiddle I had made it differently. thanks again

Comment: and I obviously need to get my eyes checked (ie m != rn ) :)

Comment: Stack Overflow has a bad font. Happens all the time ;-)